# How to parse multiple xml node to sql server

Tags: sql, xml

actually i want to parse xml to sql using following xml node
i want xml input parameter then got in Table.

```
<root>
 <Header>
<RqID>20220210125441</RqID>
</Header>
<Item>
<element>
<FromCrcy>JPY</FromCrcy>
<Rate>0.00886</Rate>
<RatioFrom>0</RatioFrom>
<RatioTo>0</RatioTo>
<ToCrcy>EUR</ToCrcy>
<ValidFrom>26.07.2010</ValidFrom>
</element>      
</Item>
<ResponseStatus>
<StatusCode>I000000</StatusCode>
<StatusDesc>Success</StatusDesc>
</ResponseStatus>
</root>
```

following script i am using to get xml to table in sql server but getting as null so please solve it.

```
Set @StrMessage = ''
    Declare @intPointer int

    Exec sp_xml_preparedocument @intPointer  OUTPUT, @MessageXML
    --PRINT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),@MessageXML)

    Create Table #Currency_bas 
    (
        RowID int Identity, RqID nvarchar(50), FromCrcy nvarchar(3), Rate Decimal(13,3), RatioFrom int, RatioTo int
        , ToCrcy nvarchar(3), ValidFrom date,StatusCode nvarchar(50),StatusDesc nvarchar(50)
    )   
    Insert Into #Currency_bas
    (
         --RqID,
         --StatusCode,StatusDesc --, --
         FromCrcy, Rate, RatioFrom, RatioTo 
        , ToCrcy, ValidFrom 
    )

    Select  
    --RqID,StatusCode,StatusDesc --, 
    FromCrcy, Rate, RatioFrom, RatioTo 
        ,ToCrcy, ValidFrom  
    From OPENXML(@intPointer, '/root',2)
    WITH 
    (
       --RqID nvarchar(50),
       --StatusCode nvarchar(50),
       --StatusDesc nvarchar(50)
        FromCrcy nvarchar(3), 
        Rate Decimal(13,3), 
        RatioFrom int, 
        RatioTo int, 
        ToCrcy nvarchar(3), 
        ValidFrom   date
    )


    SELECT FromCrcy, Rate, RatioFrom, RatioTo 
        ,ToCrcy, ValidFrom FROM #Currency_bas
```

how to parse this xml in sql table so please give me example to solve this.

Comment: A lot of examples can be found over here. What is your problem exactly?

Comment: sir i have edited my question please check again.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect your data you'll see it doesn't start at `root` it starts at `root/Item/element`

Also note the extra date conversion step.

An example of the syntax you need to get `RqID` and `Status` is here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openxml-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#b-specifying-colpattern-for-mapping-between-columns-and-the-xml-attributes

```
DECLARE @MessageXML VARCHAR(8000)

SET @MessageXML = '
<root>
 <Header><RqID>20220210125441</RqID></Header>
 <Item>
    <element>
        <FromCrcy>JPY</FromCrcy>
        <Rate>0.00886</Rate>
        <RatioFrom>0</RatioFrom>
        <RatioTo>0</RatioTo>
        <ToCrcy>EUR</ToCrcy>
        <ValidFrom>26.07.2010</ValidFrom>
    </element>      
 </Item>
 <ResponseStatus>
        <StatusCode>I000000</StatusCode>
        <StatusDesc>Success</StatusDesc>
 </ResponseStatus>
</root>
'

Declare @intPointer int

    Exec sp_xml_preparedocument @intPointer  OUTPUT, @MessageXML

    Select  
    RqID,
    StatusCode,StatusDesc, 
    FromCrcy, Rate, RatioFrom, RatioTo 
        ,ToCrcy, CONVERT(DATE,ValidFrom,104) as ValidFrom
    From OPENXML(@intPointer, '/root/Item/element',2)
    WITH 
    (
       RqID nvarchar(50) '../../Header/RqID',
       StatusCode nvarchar(50) '../../ResponseStatus/StatusCode',
       StatusDesc nvarchar(50) '../../ResponseStatus/StatusDesc',
        FromCrcy nvarchar(3), 
        Rate Decimal(13,3), 
        RatioFrom int, 
        RatioTo int, 
        ToCrcy nvarchar(3), 
        ValidFrom   varchar(100)
    )
```

Comment: thanks Nick.McDermaid its working fine

Comment: love your skill.

Comment: but header node RqID not coming currently coming as null

Comment: I knew you were going to say that... let me take a look

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please accept it if it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft proprietary `OPENXML` and its companions `sp_xml_preparedocument` and `sp_xml_removedocument` are kept just for backward compatibility with the obsolete SQL Server 2000. Their use is diminished just to very few fringe cases.

Also, folks are usually forget to call the  `sp_xml_removedocument`. And it is causing a memory leak.

Starting from SQL Server 2005 onwards, it is strongly recommended to re-write your SQL and switch it to XQuery.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @MessageXML XML = 
N'<root>
    <Header>
        <RqID>20220210125441</RqID>
    </Header>
    <Item>
        <element>
            <FromCrcy>JPY</FromCrcy>
            <Rate>0.00886</Rate>
            <RatioFrom>0</RatioFrom>
            <RatioTo>0</RatioTo>
            <ToCrcy>EUR</ToCrcy>
            <ValidFrom>26.07.2010</ValidFrom>
        </element>
    </Item>
    <ResponseStatus>
        <StatusCode>I000000</StatusCode>
        <StatusDesc>Success</StatusDesc>
    </ResponseStatus>
</root>';

SELECT RqID = @MessageXML.value('(/root/Header/RqID/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')
    , StatusCode = @MessageXML.value('(/root/ResponseStatus/StatusCode/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')
    , StatusDesc = @MessageXML.value('(/root/ResponseStatus/StatusDesc/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')
    , FromCrcy = c.value('(FromCrcy/text())[1]', 'CHAR(3)')
    , Rate = c.value('(Rate/text())[1]', 'DECIMAL(13,5)')
    , RatioFrom = c.value('(RatioFrom/text())[1]', 'INT')
    , RatioTo = c.value('(RatioTo/text())[1]', 'INT')
    , ToCrcy = c.value('(ToCrcy/text())[1]', 'CHAR(3)')
    , ValidFrom = TRY_CONVERT(DATE, c.value('(ValidFrom/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)'), 104)
FROM @MessageXML.nodes('/root/Item/element') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----------------+------------+------------+----------+---------+-----------+---------+--------+------------+
|      RqID      | StatusCode | StatusDesc | FromCrcy |  Rate   | RatioFrom | RatioTo | ToCrcy | ValidFrom  |
+----------------+------------+------------+----------+---------+-----------+---------+--------+------------+
| 20220210125441 | I000000    | Success    | JPY      | 0.00886 |         0 |       0 | EUR    | 2010-07-26 |
+----------------+------------+------------+----------+---------+-----------+---------+--------+------------+
```